# HDMI Desktop in portrait mode not working

Tags: hdmi, raspbian-stretch, 1080p

I have a Raspberry Pi 3 connected to a Toshiba TV HDMI port, which I want to use in portrait mode think to display a restaurant menu.

I have changed the **/boot/config.txt** and added the following:

```
display_rotate=3 
gpu_mem=128
```

While the display did rotate it did not work as expected. The desktop rotated 90 degrees but kept the same layout/size/resolution. Meaning the screen now shows a rotated desktop that does not cover the full screen.

I tried adding things like:

```
hdmi_cvt=1080 1920 60
```

in an attempt to force the resolution of the screen to be displayed in a 1080x1920 format (instead of the 1920x1080) but that did not work.

Any ideas on what we need to change to get the full screen to be used when rotating the view?

Answer (score 2):

Found the solution, in the **/boot/config.txt** you need to comment out *framebuffer_xx* as following:

```
# uncomment to force a console size. By default it will be display's size minus
# overscan.
#framebuffer_width=912
#framebuffer_height=492
```

Seems to be forced by default on 2018-04-18 release of raspbian.